# VHDL Plus operator `+` and Downto syntax

Tags: fpga, vhdl

Considering variable `a` and `b` as `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 DOWNTO 0)` we have `a + b` as 33 bit result;

How can we get 32 bits out of this?

Does VHDL have something like `(a+b)(31 downto 0)` or we should store `c:= a+b` and then get `c(31 downto 0)`?

Comment: Are a and b representing signed or unsigned numbers?  This is why I don't use slv for arithmetic...

Comment: they seem to be unsigned, since i did not use signed library.

Comment: It's not recommended to perform arithmetic calculations on STD_LOGIC types. Please use `ieee.numeric_std` and cast all your operands to SIGNED or UNSIGNED signals with the appropriate length. VHDL does not increase vector sizes to capture potential overflows. If you need \$C_{out}\$ then expand `a` and `b` to 33 bits by concatenation or by using the resize function.

Comment: You don't specify which package."+" you use to produce a result with length 33.

Comment: @VSB - if you don't use a library they are not anything.  They are just a bag of bits.  VHDL is strongly typed.  If you mean something to represnt a number, please use the perfectly good types available for that.  Either `integer` int he basic language or the `unsigned` and `signed` vectors from `ieee.numeric_std`.  http://parallelpoints.com/numbers-in-vhdl/

Answer (score 2):

If `a, b, c` are of type `std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)`,

then,  `c := a + b;`
will give the 32 bit answer in `c` (without carry) as you required.

If you want 33 bit answer in c (where `c` is `std_logic_vector(32 downto 0)`)

Then `c := ('0' & a) + ('0' & b)` will give the 33 bit answer.

But you will need `ieee.std_logic_unsigned` package for adding `std_logic_vector` using `+` operator.

Comment: Interesting. Personally I'd like to hear why and how this works :)

Comment: I think a misunderstanding happend. A(32)+B(32) --> OUT(33) this is due to carry out of add operation, and I want OUT[31..0].

Comment: @VSB Sorry about the misunderstanding. :)

Answer (score 0):

declare

> signal temp : std_logic_vector(32 downto 0);

and in code

> temp <= ('0' & a) + ('0' & b);
>
> c <= temp(31 downto 0);

From what I understood from your question this answer will help you. Else let me know.

Comment: I want to know is it possible to this without temp variable, somehow?

Comment: With any conventional package, `temp <= a + b` won't compile. Neither the operators in the non-standard `std_logic_unsigned` package nor those in the standard `numeric_std_unsigned` produce an output that is automatically 1 bit larger.

Comment: @fru1tbat yes you are right. Made changes. Now it is correct right?